# Vim colors cheme load on startup - linux ubuntu genome terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I am using genome terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 (just in case!)

I set my colorscheme to atomdark and I have `atomdark.vim` in both my `~/.vim/colors` and `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors`.

I set this in my `.vimrc` file

```
set t_Co=256                           
syntax enable                           
colorscheme atomdark
```

but when ever I start vim its o a different colorscheme and if I save the vimrc file by `:w` the atom dark color scheme will be set but every time I start vim I should do the saving .
If I don't, it will be on the default colorscheme every vim start.

Note: 
Tried the scriptnames and tracked down some paths but I could not understand a word of it. If it is the case I need specific help for it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem completely lost.

1. `/usr/share/vim/` is off-limits for you. Whatever you do to customize Vim, do it in `~/.vim/`.
2. The correct option is `t_Co`, not `t_CO`.
3. `265` is not a correct value. `1`, `8`, `16`, `88`, `256` are correct values.
4. That option is useless anyway. You should set up your terminal emulator correctly instead.

Comment: i fixed the line with the t_Co mistakes but it didnt solve the problem.

the main problem is vim is not loading the colorscheme n start up.

Comment: something is overriding the colorscheme after .vimrc file is specifying it.
It seems i cant find it and no idea how to fix this. I got this far at the moment.